# WebView scroll like paging

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, flutter

Is there anything similar to swift `webview.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true` in flutter WebViewWidget. I have used webview_flutter pub for webview.

If this attribute is not present then, can we achieve this using JavaScript code or draggesture?